# Assigning One Value to a Variable With Multiple Value Possibilities

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, switch-statement

There are a few instances where I've come across this and I just need to ask to see if there is something better out there. I have a value that can come through the pike that has a number assigned to it. The number means something, so to output it to the user. For example, I need to change 1 to something that means something to the user. Here's a code example:

```
switch($data['priority']) {
case 1:
    $priority = 'Low';
    break;
case 2:
    $priority = 'Medium';
    break;
case 3:
    $priority = 'High';
    break;
default:
    $priority = 'None';
    break;
}
```

Is there a way to assign the value to priority with less code? I know that in JavaScript you can do multiple ternary operators (`var data = type == 1 ? 'Good' : type == 2 ? 'Bad' : type == 3 ? 'Unknown' : '';`) but PHP doesn't allow this. I know you could also do multiple if, else if, else if, else statements, but this just seems like a lot of extra code. Is there a better way to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to use an array as map:

```
$map = array(1 => 'Low', 2 => 'Mid', ...);
$prioName = isset($map[$prio]) ? $map[$prio] : 'None';
```

Comment: That's an interesting thought. 2 lines of code compared to 14

Comment: Those are some fast fingers, Daniel! Good answer. +1!

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't happen too often that I'm faster than you ;-)

Comment: Oh -- and by the way, PHP *does* support your "cascading" of ternary operators as well, but you have to use parentheses which makes it less readable. `$prioName = $prio == 1 ? 'Low' : ($prioName == 2 ? 'Mid' : (...)));`

Comment: Yeah that's just plain ugly though. I'd feel like I jumped into a terrible Microsoft Excel spreadsheet trying to stack if statements....

Answer (score 2):

Try an array map:

```
$priorities = array('None', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High');

// you can use an easy "if"
if ($data['priority'] < 1 || $data['priority'] > 3)
    $data['priority'] = 0;

// or you can use a ternary assignment:
$data['priority'] = $data['priority'] < 1 || $data['priority'] > 3 ? 0 : $data['priority'];

$priority = $priorities[$data['priority']];
```

Comment: There's 3 lines of code. I'd shorten the if statement to a ternary statement `$data['priority'] = $data['priority'] < 1 || $data['priority'] > 3 ? 0 : $data['priority'];` I like that as well.

Comment: I like the ternary as well; this was "more" obvious and clearer for anyone new to PHP and unfamiliar with ternary operators.

Comment: @ImmortalFirefly personally, I prefer readability over minimizing lines. Plus I'm pretty sure that the `if` statement is faster in this case.

Comment: True, it probably would be a little faster and it does have better readability if that's what you're used to. I'm trying to get rid of excess lines of code....my poor finger is tired of scrolling through my scripts ;)